# No overload for 'textBox1_TextChanged_1' matches delegate 'System.Threading.TimerCallback

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to use `System.Threading.Timer` so that I can use this timer to call method "`CreateThread`" which is as follows.

```
public void CreateThread()
    {
        th1 = new Thread(ChangeLabel);
        th1.Start();
    }
```

I am getting error at line:

```
public void textBox1_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       TimerCallback tcb = new TimerCallback(CreateThread); //This line is showing error
    }
```

Can anybody please explain what is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TimerCallback expects a `state` property in the delegate:

```
public void CreateThread(object state)
    {
        th1 = new Thread(ChangeLabel);
        th1.Start();
    }
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timercallback.aspx):

```
public delegate void TimerCallback(
    Object state
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your method signature doesn't match with the [`TimerCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timercallback.aspx) delegate.It takes an object as parameter, but your method takes nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timercallback.aspx) for the `TimerCallback` delegate, you will see that it has a signature of `void TimerCallback(object)`.

The method you want the timer to call needs the same signature so that it will compile.

Something like this would fix it:

```
public void CreateThread()
{
    CreateThread(null);
}

private void CreateThread(object state)
{
    th1 = new Thread(ChangeLabel);
    th1.Start();
}
```

This would allow any existing callers of `CreateThread()` to remain unchanged, whilst giving you a method with the correct signature to call the method.

Alternatively, you could do the following by using a lambda:

```
public void textBox1_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   TimerCallback tcb = new TimerCallback(() => CreateThread());
}
```